# Deprecated code in iOS 6 fallback to iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6, fallback

I have this custom back button:

```
- (IBAction)backToMenu:(id)sender {

[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

}
```

Testing my app in the iOS 6 simulator says dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated, and I must use dismissViewControllerAnimated instead, so, how I can use the iOS 6 code and fallback to iOS 5

I have tried this:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:(YES) completion:nil];
else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController:animated:)])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    NSLog(@"Oooops, what system is this ?!!! - should never see this !");
```

But without results, I'm seeing the NSLog and no view is dismissed, any hints?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selectors you're testing for aren't the same as the selectors you're calling. Try the following:

```
if([self.presentingViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:(YES) completion:nil];
else if([self.presentingViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)])
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    NSLog(@"Oooops, what system is this ?!!! - should never see this !");
```

The important difference is that the *object you're calling* - `self.presentingViewController`, in this case - is different from the *method you're calling on that object*. We call the latter a selector, and that's the bit you want to put inside the `@selector()` wrapper.

Comment: And sometimes it's better to test the version of the OS and use that to select a path.  And no matter how you test, you can set a (relatively) global variable so you only test once and then select which path based on the (tidy) global flag rather than the (messy) `respondsToSelector` expression.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, very well explained, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil]; for iOS 6